# About the integral $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2 -(x-\xi)^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals, exponential-function, convolution

everyone.

While solving a PDE, I used Poisson's formula for the diffusion equation, which eventually gave me an integral:

$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\pi t}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\xi^2}e^{\frac{-(x-\xi)^2}{4t}}d\xi$$

where $t$ and $x$ are parameters.

(This is essentially a convolution of a gaussian with another gaussian, shifted by $x$ and rescaled by $4t$.)

I kind of struggle to take this integral.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complete square, translate and use the fact that $\int e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$

First, notice that $x^2+(x-\xi)^2= \left(\sqrt{2}x-\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2+\frac{\xi^2}{2}$ ("complete the square"). Then, $e^{-x^2-(x-\xi)^2}=e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}}e^{-\left(\sqrt{2}x-\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2}.$ Integrate now,
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\Bbb R} dx e^{-x^2-(x-\xi)^2} &= e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}}\int\limits_{\Bbb R} dx e^{-\left(\sqrt{2}x-\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2} \\
&= \dfrac{e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}} \int\limits_{\Bbb R} dx e^{-x^2}\\
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Well, have been trying to do just that for the past few hours. Could you expand a bit, please?

Comment: I am a bit amazed that people doing PDE don't know how to complete the square. No offense, but it is striking.

Comment: In his book "Infinitesimal Calculus" the mathematician Jean Dieudonné (advisor of well-known field-medallist Grothendieck and scribe of Nicolás Bourbaki) stated that is sorry and pathetic that nowdays the mathematicians prefer "abstraction" over being able to perform calculations, specially for the first year undergraduates. It is kind of true; when I studied myself undergrad, we believe to be "better" because we "understood" the abstract "high-end" mathematics (we would mock of the engineers or physicists) but we ourselves would not be able to solve a simple ODE... how pathetic we were.

Comment: Anyways, @VladimirNikishkin do you see know what do? There is a change of variables somewhere in the edit that I didn't write out explicitly, but it is rather obvious.

Comment: Don't be arrogant, Will M. , please. I haven't done any calculus in ~5 years. Of course I forgot a lot.

Comment: I wasn't. I was afraid my comment might be taken as arrogant but it is hard to write something critizing and write it in such a way that a neutral sentiment is understood.

Answer (score 0):

@Will M. provides help.

This is from Mathematica:
$$
 \int \exp \left(-x^2-(x-\xi )^2\right) \, dx =
 \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{\xi ^2}{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{2 x-\xi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-x^2-(x-\xi )^2\right) \, dx =
\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{\xi ^2}{2}}
$$

As you noted, the shape is Gaussian. For this plot $\xi=-2$.

[image: gaussian]